# Why is there a な in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, i-adjectives, auxiliaries

I am translating the following sentence I found in my workbook.

> 美味しそう**な**写真を見て、思わず[涎]{よだれ}が出た。

`美味しい` is an i-adjective, so why is there a `な`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't simply 美味しい, but 美味しそう. The そう suffix means 'appears to be', and it takes な.

> When I saw a photo of delicious-looking food, I couldn't help but drool.

Answer (score 6):

This そうな is the 連体形{れんたいけい} (attributive form) of verbal auxiliary そうだ, which indicates mode.

美味{おい}し is the stem of 美味{おい}しい. The verbal auxiliary そうだ is placed after the stem of an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

Oishii (i-adjective): The food actually tastes good.

Oishisou (with sou auxiliary verb): The food looks good.

Sou auxiliary verb expresses "seem" or "look" together with a verb, i-adjective, or na-adjective.

(sou examples)

> with verb:
>   [雨]{あめ}が[降]{ふ}りそうだ (ame ga furisou da): Looks like it will rain.
>
> with i-adjective:
>   これは[高]{たか}そうだ (kore wa takasou da): It looks expensive.
>
> with na-adjective:
>   そこはにぎやかそうだ (soko wa nigiyaka sou da): That place looks lively.

And then putting na after sou makes a modifier to a noun.
(examples)

> [高]{たか}そうな[時計]{とけい} (takasou na tokei) expensive-looking watch
>   おいしそうな[食]{た}べ[物]{もの} (oishisou na tabemono) delicious-looking food

Comment: You may want to avoid translating 助動詞 as "auxiliary verb" in this context. Most foreigners who would ask this type of question won't be familiar with that term.